# Escaping % in django sql query gives list out of range

Tags: python, sql, django, django-rest-framework

I tried running following SQL query in pgadmin and it worked:

```
 SELECT <columns>
 FROM <tables>
 WHERE 
     date_visited >= '2023-05-26 07:05:00'::timestamp 
     AND date_visited <= '2023-05-26 07:07:00'::timestamp
     AND url LIKE '%/mymodule/api/myurl/%';
```

I wanted to call the same url in django rest endpoint. So, I wrote code as follows:

```
with connection.cursor() as cursor:
    cursor.execute('''
        SELECT <columns>
        FROM <tables>
        WHERE 
            date_visited >= '%s'::timestamp 
            AND date_visited <=  '%s'::timestamp
            AND url LIKE '%%%s%%';
        ''', [from_date, to_date, url])
```

But it is giving me list index out of range error. I guess I have made mistake with `'%%%s%%'`. I tried to escale `%` in original query with `%%`. But it does not seem to work. Whats going wrong here?

Comment: Please *don't* use raw SQL queries. Use Django's ORM. Can you share the model you are working with?

Comment: Is using raw SQL have significant disadvantage? I used raw SQL because the query is not that simple. I abstracted it out with `<columns>` and `tables`. Equivalent ORM was getting too complex, but I felt SQL was relatively crispier.

Comment: Does the error happen on this actual code?  Because there aren't any list indexes  here.  Does the error happen later, when you try to _fetch_ the results?

Comment: Yes, it is dialect-specific, it is often less safe because constructing SQL queries with arbitrary fields makes it vulnerable to injection and most importantly, the result can not be post-processed with extra `QuerySet` methods, which will nullify a lot of Django's features.

Answer (score 2):

You can [**`.filter(…)`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/querysets/#filter) with:

```
MyModel.objects.filter(
    date_visited__between=('2023-05-26 07:05:00', '2023-05-26 07:07:00'),
    url__contains='/mymodule/api/myurl/',
)
```

Here we can use the [**`__contains`** lookup <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/querysets/#std-fieldlookup-contains) for a *case-sensitive* match.

Answer (score 2):

Prepared statements add quotes auto matically to prevent SQL injection

So your code would look like

```
with connection.cursor() as cursor:
    cursor.execute('''
        SELECT <columns>
        FROM <tables>
        WHERE 
            date_visited >= %s::timestamp 
            AND date_visited <=  %s::timestamp
        AND url LIKE %s;
    ''', [from_date, to_date,"%" + url + "%"])
```

Comment: I used your code and it was still giving me same error. I also had comment in those triple quotes. Though those were valid postgresql comments prefixed by `--`, for example `-- timestamp like 2023-05-26 07:05:00 `, weirdly it was giving me list index out of bounds! Removing those comments eliminated the error.